# Why doesen't the number 2 work in this for-loop?

Tags: iphone, arrays, for-loop

I have a function that runs trough each element in an array.
It's hard to explain, so I'll just paste in the code here:

```
NSLog(@"%@", arraySub);

for (NSNumber *favoriteThing in arrayFav){  

    int favoriteLoop = [favoriteThing intValue] + favCount;
    NSLog(@"%d", favoriteLoop);

    id arrayFavObject = [array objectAtIndex:favoriteLoop];
    [arrayFavObject retain];
    [array removeObjectAtIndex:favoriteLoop];
    [array insertObject:arrayFavObject atIndex:0];
    [arrayFavObject release];

    id arraySubFavObject = [arraySub objectAtIndex:favoriteLoop];
    [arraySubFavObject retain];
    [arraySub removeObjectAtIndex:favoriteLoop];
    [arraySub insertObject:arraySubFavObject atIndex:0];
    [arraySubFavObject release];

    id arrayLengthFavObject = [arrayLength objectAtIndex:favoriteLoop];
    [arrayLengthFavObject retain];
    [arrayLength removeObjectAtIndex:favoriteLoop];
    [arrayLength insertObject:arrayLengthFavObject atIndex:0];
    [arrayLengthFavObject release];

}

NSLog(@"%@", arraySub);
```

The array `arrayFav` contains these numbers: `3, 8, 2, 10, 40`.
Array `array` contains 92 strings with a name.
Array `arraySub` contains numbers `0` to `91`, representing a filename with a title from the array `array`.
Array `arrayLength` contains 92 strings representing the size of each file from array `arraySub`.

Now, the first `NSLog` shows, as expected, the numbers 0 to 91.
The `NSLog`-s in the loop shows the numbers `3, 8, 2, 10, 40`, also as expected.

But here's the odd part: the last `NSLog` shows these numbers:
`40, 10, 0, 8, 3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91`

that is 40, 10, **0**, 8, 3, and so on.

It was not supposed to be a zero in there, it was supposed to be a 2..

Do you have any idea at why this is happening or a way to fix it? Thank you.

EDIT: Code has changed. `arrayFav` now contains numbers.

Comment: Try `CFShowStr(string);` in the for-loop.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706225/why-doesent-the-number-2-work-in-this-for-loop

Comment: Looks like your "number 2" is actually `@"0x64356f8"`.

Comment: Probably you should paste the result somewhere that supports a line break :(.

Comment: @KennyTM: Yeah..

Anyway, that doesent matter anymore, as the `arrayFav` now contains numbers. Check main-question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by removing the for-loop and just search for the correct location in the arraySub.

```
// If the object is not really the object we want, get what we want
if (favoriteLoop != [[[arraySub objectAtIndex:favoriteLoop] description] intValue]){
    favoriteLoop = [arraySub indexOfObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", favoriteLoop]];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `-intValue` method returns 0 [if there is something funky](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-intValue) about the beginning of the string being converted.

Instead of using `NSString` to store integers, try using `NSNumber` to enforce storing numbers in your array, or debug what is being sent the `-intValue` message.

Comment: Quote:
`Now, the first NSLog shows, as expected, the numbers 0 to 91. The NSLog-s in the loop shows the numbers 3, 8, 2, 10, 40, also as expected.`

Comment: Using `NSNumber` to hold unsigned integers may be easier to debug.

Comment: True. But the array loads data from a plist, would'nt that be a headache to do?

Comment: No, it's not a headache, since you can store the numbers in your plist as a "Number", which means it'll get loaded as an `NSNumber` for you.

Comment: I don't think so, since plist files support storing `NSNumber` instances: cf. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_list#Mac_OS_X

Comment: This is also described here: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/plist.5.html

Comment: Okay, I have done that now. Changes to code in first post.

It didn't help, though.

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong, but if this is working for all indices except for the index associated with changes to the "2" `NSNumber` object, I would start by debugging the state of everything going on in that loop, at that index.